# how to allow netcat-like connection to graphical interface (KDE, GNOME)

Tags: gnome, kde, remote-control

I'd like to use my linux server KDE remotely. Is there anyway to do this?

It seems that KDM is running as a TCP service, but I am unsure whether I can use this to connect remotely to graphic interface.

I'd also like to know the case of GNOME.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your server has an SSH daemon running, you can forward X traffic over an SSH tunnel quite easily:

```
localhost$  ssh -X your.server.address
   server$  xclock   # window should appear on local machine
```

If you want to log in to see your entire desktop remotely, read about Xdmcp. [Here's an easy resource](http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tips/6698/1).

Answer (score 0):

[x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/) is a different solution, instead of launching single applications over the tunnel, you remote attach to the remote existing desktop session and control it with the local input devices. Install `x11vnc` on the remote computer, and enable `sshd`. From the local computer, create a SSH tunnel:

```
ssh -t -L 5900:localhost:5900 remote-host-name 'x11vnc -localhost -forever -display :0'
```

Run a VNC client on the local computer and connect to localhost, protocol VNC, port 5900, display 0 or the like. I can recommend [KRDC](http://www.kde.org/applications/internet/krdc/).

When you are done, close the VNC client, then kill the SSH session to tear town the tunnel.